# OPUS Make error: OPUS MAKE: Unknown status. Stop

Tags: cmake, makefile, gnu-make

We are using OPUS Make in our build infrastructure. (Basically traditional make with some wrappers around I guess)
Our codebase is mostly Java and I have been making changes and building for many months now. No issues.
Suddenly, a couple of days back, when I tried to build,i started seeing this error:

```
OPUS MAKE: Unknown status. Stop.
```

I see this error no matter what I try to build. More imp - it looks like it is not even trying to actually compile my code and for some reason just stops before with the above error.

I tried doing a clean build. Even manually cleaned up all old generated build files. Still did not work.
I even tried restarting my environment itself. Restarted Clearcase. Still no use.

I see there is a way to build with debug information. Did that also `make -d`
However, that did not give any useful info either. Just the same line as above. I was hoping that it would give some debug logs or some error code that I could use to solve the problem.

I see there is an option: `make -n`. That comes out clean. But from the name, it looks like it does not even attempt to run the build itself.

Please suggest what the issue could be.

thx - Om

Answer (score 0):

"Unknown status" means that a shell command in a target returned a status that make did not understand.  Run with `-d` to see which command is failing.  And debug that shell command.